# How can i edit the w3schools code to let two or more modal images on click?

Tags: javascript, html, image, modal-dialog, image-enlarge

I am unable to call the function to display modal after an image is being clicked for multiple images. Currently it is working only for one image. If the id assigned to the variable in the js code and the html code is the same for all images, then shouldn't the function work for all the images and not only one? I basically have a website wherein i need 12 images to be displayed. and each should get enlarged when clicked upon. Just like in the w3 school code.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img1");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;    /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;       /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<img id="myImg" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img1">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img1">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: css "id" selector can only be used once in an html page.

Comment: id selector must be unique, kindly use class selector instead of id selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id should be unique to each element

Hope the below snippet helps

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
function showmodal(id){
  var img = document.getElementById(id);
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = img.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = img.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>


<img id="myImg" onclick="showmodal('myImg')" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Flower" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<img id="myImg1" onclick="showmodal('myImg1')" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg" alt="landscape" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess i understood my mistake. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can't work with multiple id-s on one page. The main sense of `id` (identifier) is to be unique, and available with exact name.

It needs rewrite, so I added a simple script, without changing general styles:

```js
handleModalPopup();

function handleModalPopup(){
  let mod = GetModalComponents();
  
  let img = document.querySelectorAll('.img');
  
  for( let i = 0; i < img.length; i++ ){
    img[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      mod.modal.style.display = "block";
      mod.img.src = this.src; // `this` references to clicked image
      mod.caption.textContent = this.getAttribute('alt');
    });
  }
  
  mod.close.onclick = function(){
    mod.modal.style.display = "none";
  } // Google → onclick vs addEventListener
}

function GetModalComponents(){
  let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  
  return {
    modal: modal,
    close: modal.querySelector('.close'),
    img: modal.querySelector('.modal-content'),
    caption: modal.querySelector('.caption'),
  }; // yes, you can save the links to HTML elements in one object.
}
```

```css
.img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;    /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;       /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="https://gyazo.com/fe48322c44d1c214ee8d9ba49876a0da.png" alt="one">

<img class="img" src="https://gyazo.com/c708f879e56f725318fafca74b9cbe7f.png" alt="Two">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content">
  <div class="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Any questions ?)

Comment: None. Thanks a lot.